# Spring Security Access Denied with Spring Boot 3.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm doing a pet project of a social network and I'm having problems with authorization.I getting Access Denied when I send a request with a jwt token.

I am doing the following chain of actions:

1. Registration where I specify the login email and password (Works well)
2. Authorization where by login and password I get a token (Works well)
3. I'm trying to send a request in the postman with the received token where I get an error(Access Denied)

Whats wrong with my code?

My Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity( proxyTargetClass = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig  {  
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/swagger/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/auth/test/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/h2/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        
        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

AythTokenFilter:

```
@Slf4j
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String accessToken = parseJwt(request);
            if (accessToken != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(accessToken)) {
                String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(accessToken);

                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e.getMessage());
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return headerAuth.substring(7, headerAuth.length());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

JWTUtils:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class JwtUtils {

    @Value("${jwt.token.secret}")
    private String jwtSecret;

    @Value("${jwt.token.jwtExpirationMs}")
    private int jwtExpirationMs;

    public String generateJwtToken(UserDetailsImpl userPrincipal) {
        return generateTokenFromUsername(userPrincipal.getUsername());
    }

    public String generateTokenFromUsername(String username) {
        return Jwts.builder().setSubject(username).setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + jwtExpirationMs)).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
                .compact();
    }

    public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }

    public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            log.error("Invalid JWT signature: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            log.error("Invalid JWT token: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            log.error("JWT token is expired: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            log.error("JWT token is unsupported: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            log.error("JWT claims string is empty: {}", e.getMessage());
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

Controller method:

```
@GetMapping("/requests")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    public UsernamesResponse getFriendRequests() {
        return userService.getFriendRequests();
    }
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.authorization.method.AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.attemptAuthorization(AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.java:257) ~[spring-security-core-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.authorization.method.AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.java:198) ~[spring-security-core-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752) ~[spring-aop-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703) ~[spring-aop-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at ru.effectivemobile.socialnetwork.controller.UserController$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getFriendRequests(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1003) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:880) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:110) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at ru.effectivemobile.socialnetwork.security.jwt.AuthTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthTokenFilter.java:47) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilterInternal(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.0.jar:6.0.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:351) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

**EDIT 1**

Jwt token example:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ0ZXN0IiwiaWF0IjoxNjg1NjIyMjc4LCJleHAiOjE2ODU2MjU4Nzh9.A_gw2V1c403vxANRcO5LCU7621TMYvYeBKKb-YJv_ZTjEPKym140YAlIjnqAOhoQtfhKRm2O-pJke-7zzglzSg
```

**EDIT 2**
[image: AuthTokenFilter Debug]
[image: Signup]
[image: Getting tokens]
[image: Error]

Comment: If I read the token with https://jwt.io/ the payload only contains {"sub": "test", "iat": 1685622278, "exp": 1685625878 }. Your token creator needs to add the role as a claim - have a look at  generateAccessToken() here - https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/spring-security-jwt-role-based-authorization. If you fail, add the code that generates the jwt token to the question and I will have a go.

Comment: @JohnWilliams I get the UserDetail from username from token in the method doFilterInternal() of the AuthnTokenFilter class and then assign the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken object
in SecurityContext . Isn't that enough to get all the user data? Could you please take a look at my JwtUtils class?

Comment: No that's not enough. The users ROLEs are missing. They are supposed to be in the JWT as a claim. The filter will put the  ROLES into the SecurityContextHolder context with this statement SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication). Set a breakpoint before this line and you will see there are no roles (or authorities) in authentication.

Comment: Can you add enough code for me to simulate, including jwt generator and web config and security config.

Comment: @JohnWilliams i shared project on github https://github.com/Vsevolod-Tsukanov/social-network. Thanks for your help i really appreciate it

Comment: In your screenshot your `authentication ` object contains a password. How is taht possible, if you set the password to `null` one line earlier?

Comment: @dur i dont know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem relates to the difference in Spring between ROLES and Authorities and the [Spring hack that treats Roles as Authorities prefixed with "ROLE_"](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-granted-authority-vs-role)

In order to use the annotation `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")` you need a `Permission` as follows:

```
ROLE_USER("ROLE_USER")
```

Which is related to your `ERole` enum as follows:
`ROLE_USER(Set.of(Permission.ROLE_USER, Permission.READ))`

If you are only using the `Permission.READ`, etc for Controller level authority checking then drop them.

Alternatively use annotation like this `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthotity('READ')")`and drop the roles.

I have made changes (on branch fix/authorities at https://github.com/KoosieDeMoer/social-network.git) with stubbed out repo that work.

Comment: Use your ROLES (USER & ADMIN) as simplegrant authorities and drop the permissions level.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I couldn't have done it without you

Comment: @SmetanaPoAktsii I have added an answer that shows the complete/proper use of a JWT in your code. I have deleted my for of your project.

Answer (score 0):

You are only using half the power of the JWT approach. As a result you are doing a DB read in `TokenAuthFilter` for every request. This is very inefficient.

If you extract the JSON contents of your current JWT it contains the following:

```
{
  "sub": "test",
  "iat": 1685622278,
  "exp": 1685625878
}
```

It would be better (and pretty standard) if the token contained the following:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ0ZXN0IiwiZW1haWwiOiJ0ZXN0QG1haWwuY29tIiwicm9sZXMiOiJST0xFX1VTRVIiLCJpYXQiOjE2ODU3NzY5MDAsImV4cCI6MTY4NTc4MDUwMH0.tR5ikXzTEs4dmDfANi69QgI-LjW424fzNu_spovqnyWPzcSfvboTu8fZLHFZFOFFIH3299HFXVYNor0-IcgyBg
```

.

```
{
  "sub": "test",
  "email": "test@mail.com",
  "roles": "ROLE_USER",
  "iat": 1685776900,
  "exp": 1685780500
}
```

Because it contains the roles and email, it removes the need for the TokenAuthFilter to read this info from the DB for each incoming request.

The following is the example implementation on your code:

**JwtUtils**

```
public String generateJwtToken(UserDetailsImpl userPrincipal) {
    return Jwts.builder().setSubject(userPrincipal.getUsername()).claim("email", userPrincipal.getEmail()).claim("roles", userPrincipal.getRole()).setIssuedAt(new Date())
    .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + jwtExpirationMs)).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
    .compact();
}

public UserDetails getUserPrincipalFromJwtToken(String token) {
    User partialUser = new User();
    
    Claims jwtBody = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    partialUser.setUserName(jwtBody.get("sub", String.class));
    partialUser.setEmail(jwtBody.get("email", String.class));
    String role = jwtBody.get("roles", String.class);
    partialUser.setRole(ERole.valueOf(role));
    
    return UserDetailsImpl.build(partialUser);
}
```

**AuthTokenFilter**

```
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        String accessToken = parseJwt(request);
        if (accessToken != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(accessToken)) {

            UserDetails userDetails = jwtUtils.getUserPrincipalFromJwtToken(accessToken);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null,
                    userDetails.getAuthorities());
            authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e.getMessage());
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

**AuthService**

```
public JwtResponse authenticate(SigninRequest request){
    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
            .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.username(), request.password()));

 

   SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    UserDetailsImpl userDetails = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();

    String accessToken = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(userDetails);

    ERole role  = userDetails.getRole();

    RefreshToken refreshToken = refreshTokenService.createRefreshToken(userDetails.getId());

    return new JwtResponse(accessToken,refreshToken.getToken());
}

public NewTokensResponse updateToken(UpdateTokenRequest request){
    String requestRefreshToken = request.refreshToken();

    return refreshTokenService.findByToken(requestRefreshToken)
            .map(refreshTokenService::verifyExpiration)
            .map(RefreshToken::getUser)
            .map(user -> {
                String token = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(UserDetailsImpl.build(user));
                return new NewTokensResponse(token, requestRefreshToken);
            })

            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Refresh token is not in database"));
}
```

[This is a good resource.](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/spring-security-jwt-role-based-authorization)